# From big tar.gz to Sqlite with multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, python-multiprocessing

I have big tar.gz file (11GB with more than 3 millions of csv files). It is stock market data - there is one csv file for each day. Every day has its own folder. Every csv file contains minute data for one symbol.

I am trying to unpack all the data into Sqlite database. In database I would like to join all the data for the same symbol.

To speed things up I tried to use multiprocessing module (for the first time).
The code starts, it writes to databases, uses all cores of my computer, uses all memory. At first there is 12 python process running. But after while (writing about 480Mb to a database), the python processes dies and the script stops. It stops with no error, it just stops doing anything in the middle of work.
Any help how to implement better solution?

The code:

```
import tarfile
import re
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

tar = tarfile.open('data.tar.gz')
mem=tar.getmembers()
names=tar.getnames()

# create new database
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///SP500_minute.db')

def process_file(name):
    process = 0
    # lets try if we can get ticker from the path - if yes, we can process to extract the data
    try:
        ticker = re.search(r"_([a-z0-9\.]+)\.csv$", name[1]).group(1).upper()
        process = 1 #the file is csv, we can store the data in db
        print("processing", name[1], ticker)
    except:
        print ("error", name[1], ticker)


    if process == 1:
        f = tar.extractfile(mem[name[0]])
        content = f.readlines()
        # lets decode binary to utf8, strip the end lines and split by comma to list of lists
        lines = [x.decode('utf8').strip().split(',') for x in content]
        # we can now create dataframe
        frame = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=['date', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'split_factor',
                                             'earnings', 'dividends'])
        # now write frame to db. If table exists append data
        frame.to_sql(ticker, engine, if_exists='append')
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())  # process per core
        pool.map(process_file, enumerate(names))  # process enumerate(names) iterable with pool
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

print('done processing')
```